# sed utility remove all characters in the file

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to remove the first two characters from a text file using sed:

```
$ sed -r 's/.{2}//' C:/Users/User/Desktop/text3.txt > C:/Users/User/Desktop/text3.txt
```

The file contains:

```
< >gi|1786217|gb|AE000114|ECAE000114 Escherichia coli , caiF, caiE, caiD, caiC, caiB, caiA, caiT, fixA, fixB, fixC, fixX, yaaU genes from bases 34087 to 47220 (section 4 of 400) of the complete genome
< TAATACGGTTCTCTGATGAGGACCGTTTTTTTTTGCCCATTAAGTAAATCTTTTGGGGAATCGATATTTT
< TGATGACATAAGCAGGATTTAGCTCACACTTATCGACGGTGAAGTTGCATACTATCGATATATCCACAAT
< TTTAATATGGCCTTGTTTAATTGCTTCAAAACGAGTCATAGCCAGACTTTTAATTTGTGAAACTGGAGTT
```

It removes all characters from the file and make it empty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `^` to mark start of line:

With GNU sed:

```
sed -r 's/^.{2}//' file
```

If you want to edit your file "in place" use sed's option `-i`.

And a simpler way to select two characters is to repeat the dot `..`.
In which case the `-r` is not needed, the `-i` option eliminates the redirection:

```
sed -i 's/^..//' file
```

Comment: The same result, it delete the whole file

Comment: Avoid reading from file `C:/Users/User/Desktop/text3.txt` and writing to **same** file with output redirection (`> C:/Users/User/Desktop/text3.txt`).

Comment: No way to rewrite the same file?

Comment: If you want to edit your file "in place" use sed's option -i.

Comment: I try: (sed -i 's/^.{2}//' file ) but it does not change the file

Comment: Take a look at sed's manual or try `sed -i''` or `sed -i ''`. Perhaps your sed has no option `-i`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107460/discussion-between-alaa-and-cyrus).

Comment: The `-r` is not available in all implementations, in which case you have to escape the braces `^.\{2\}`.  Easier to use `^..`.